# Storing list of objects in Django model

Tags: python, django

Is there a way in Django to have multiple objects stored and manageable (in Django admin) inside another object?

Example, I have two models: Items and RMA.  The RMA may have multiple Items inside of it.  Each Item is unique in the sense that it is an inventoried part, so I can't just reference the same item multiple times with foreignKey (though maybe I'm misunderstanding its use/implementation).

So for now, I have an Item model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    part_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And an RMA model:

```
class RMA(models.Model):
    number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    items = ?????
```

Ultimately I'd like to be able to maintain use of the Django admin functionality to add/remove items from an RMA if necessary, so I've been staying away from serializing a list and then deserializing on display.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're modeling a [has-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) relationship.

This would be modeled with a [Foreign Key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) on Item to RMA:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    part_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rma = models.ForeignKey(RMA)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

To make it accessible in the admin of `RMA` you need djangos [InlineAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) functionality.

You can find examples in the [django tutorial part2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/#adding-related-objects).

Answer (score 5):

You are effectively describing a [Many-To-One relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) and to do this you are going to have to add the [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) reference to the `Item` model, not to the `RMA` model.

You can also add a [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to give the `RMA` model an attribute that you can call.

For example:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    rma = models.ForeignKey(RMA,related_name="items")
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # etc...
```

To manage the creation of these, you'll need an [InlineModelAdmin form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects), so your `admin.py` file will need to look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item

class RMAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ItemInline,
    ]
```